# Cannot connect to the internet without first clicking on Network connection

Tags: networking

Using Ubuntu 14.04

I have a wired static IP configured on my machine.

After I boot up, I am on my LAN but I cannot browse the internet until I click my configured connection from the task bar. I then see a connected banner/icon and can browse.

How can I get it to work automatically?

Comment: How did you set up your static IP address? In Network Manager or how? Did you also set up DNS nameservers?

Answer (score 2):

Click through the Task Bar -> **Edit Connections** -> Click on your connection -> **Edit** -> select the **General** tab and check the box marked **Automatically connect to this network when it is available** and the box marked **All users may connect to this network**. Click <kbd>Save</kbd> then <kbd>Close</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I set up static IP on my router and deleted the connection on my Ubuntu machine.

Then I set up a new DCHP connection on Ubuntu and restarted the machine.

The static IP worked but I was still having the same issue.
I ended up adding **Additional DNS Servers = 8.8.8.8** and that seemed to fix my issue.